# how to create convert octal to biner?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a problem when I input numbers 2,5,7 the results are ok and when I input numbers 1,3,4,6 the results don't match.

```
define variable oct as character.
define variable l-oct as integer.
define variable oktal as integer.
define variable l-oktal  as integer.
define variable count as integer.
define variable i as integer.
define variable bin as character.
define variable bin2 as character.

end.

do i = length(bin) to 1 by -1:
  bin2 = bin2 + substring(bin, i, 1).
end.

display bin2 with frame a down.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` `else if` train is missing an `else if`. An `if` `else if` train is usually better served by a `case` statement.

Additionally, you are first constructing a back to front *in groups of three digits* binary string and subsequently reversing this at the end *per digit*.

So where octal `1` becomes binary `001` you are flipping this to `100`. Instead of flipping afterwards, concatenate your string correctly to start with, so replace all occurrences of:

`bin = bin + 'xxx'`

with:

`bin = 'xxx' + bin`